# memcached and performance

Tags: java, performance, caching, memcached, spymemcached

I might be asking very basic question, but could not find a clear answer by googling, so putting it here.

Memcached caches information in a separate Process. Thus in order to get the cached information requires inter-process communication (which is generally serialization in java). That means, generally, to fetch a cached object, we need to get a serialized object and generally transport it to network.

Both, serialization and network communication are costly operations. if memcached needs to use both of these (generally speaking, there might be cases when network communication is not required), then how Memcached is fast? Is not replication a better solution?

Or this is a tradeoff of distribution/platform independency/scalability vs performance?

Comment: AFAIK, It holds a master copy in the separate process. It also keeps cached copies locally.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I assume 'it' means client. Yes, client can store the cache locally, but it may add to the complexity of invalidations, is not it? Meaning, even the client has to maintain the caching strategies including invalidations, size, etc.

Comment: That is true. Having a coherent distributed cache is not a simple problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that looking something up in a shared cache (like memcached) is slower than looking it up in a local cache (which is what i think you mean by "replication").

However, the advantage of a shared cache is that it is shared, which means each user of the cache has access to more cache than if the memory was used for a local cache.

Consider an application with a 50 GB database, with ten app servers, each dedicating 1 GB of memory to caching. If you used local caches, then each machine would have 1 GB of cache, equal to 2% of the total database size. If you used a shared cache, then you have 10 GB of cache, equal to 20% of the total database size. Cache hits would be somewhat faster with the local caches, but the cache hit rate would be much higher with the shared cache. Since cache misses are astronomically more expensive than either kind of cache hit, slightly slower hits are a price worth paying to reduce the number of misses.

Now, the exact tradeoff does depend on the exact ratio of the costs of a local hit, a shared hit, and a miss, and also on the distribution of accesses over the database. For example, if all the accesses were to a set of 'hot' records that were under 1 GB in size, then the local caches would give a 100% hit rate, and would be just as good as a shared cache. Less extreme distributions could still tilt the balance.

In practice, the optimum configuration will usually (IMHO!) be to have a small but very fast local cache for the hottest data, then a larger and slower cache for the long tail. You will probably recognise that as the shape of other cache hierarchies: consider the way that processors have small, fast L1 caches for each core, then slower L2/L3 caches shared between all the cores on a single die, then perhaps yet slower off-chip caches shared by all the dies in a system (do any current processors actually use off-chip caches?).

Comment: Thanks for the nice explaination!

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I cannot mark multiple as accepted answers, but mix of all answers clears a lot doubt. The biggest thing I learned is that Memcached and traditional caches (like EHCache, etc) are not complimentary. Each has trade-off and may fit differently in different applications.

Comment: The premise that "cache misses are astronomically more expensive than either kind of cache hit" is wrong if your db schema, indexes and queries are well optimized for your applications. In those cases, memcached may actually slow down your website. Learnt this the hard way.

Comment: @SeunOsewa: Interesting point. Could you say a little more? Was it that your memcached hits were expensive, or your misses were cheap? Were misses hitting a cache in the database?

Comment: Also, now i come to look at some actual numbers, i see that memcached hits cost around 20-30 ms. That's huge! Cache hits on an in-memory cache should take less than a millisecond. When a disk seek is <10 ms, even a query which misses the DB cache stands a chance of being faster. I take it all back!

Answer (score 4):

You are neglecting the cost of disk i/o in your your consideration, which is generally going to be the slowest part of any process, and is the main driver IMO for utilizing in-memory caching like memcached.

Comment: I agree with cost of Disk I/O which is higher than network I/O and serialization but 1. Caching would involve extra cost of maintaining caching strategy (invalidations, etc). 2. Replication seems better since clients are talking to RAM only. Network I/O will happen behind the scenes and should not impact visible performance.

Comment: @SandeepJindal If you are talking specifically about accessing database resources there are certainly arguments to be made for one technology over the other for speeding up data reads.  Replication does however present data consistency problems due to replication lag.  So at the end of the day, it really comes down to what is the best solution for a particular application.

Answer (score 1):

Memory caches use ram memory over the network. Replication uses both ram-memory as well as persistent disk memory to fetch data. Their purposes are very different.

If you're only thinking of using Memcached to store easily obtainable data such as 1-1 mapping for table records :you-re-gonna-have-a-bad-time:.

On the other hand if your data is the entire result-set of a complex SQL query that may even oveflow the SQL memory pool (and need to be temporarily written to disk to be fetched) you're going to see a big speed-up.

The previous example mentions needing to write data to disk for a **read** operation - yes it happens if the result set is too big for memory (imagine a `CROSS JOIN`) that means that you both read and write to that drive (thrashing comes to mind).

In A highly optimized application written in C for example you may have a total processing time of 1microsec and may need to wait for networking and/or serialization/deserialization (marshaling/unmarshaling) for a much longer time than the app execution time itself. That's when you'll begin too feel the limitations of memory-caching over the network.